# Issues with buffer of mat3x3

Tags: c++, opengl

When I try to upload a buffer of mat3x3s to a storage buffer, the matrices don't work.

```
layout(packed, binding = 0) readonly buffer matrix_buffer
{
    mat3x3 matrix[];
};

...

gl_Position = vec4(vec3(pos, 0.0f) * matrix[gl_InstanceID], 1.0);
//doesn't work (nothing rendered)

gl_Position = vec4(vec3(pos, 0.0f) * mat3(1.0), 1.0);
//works
```

However, I have no issues when using mat4x4.

```
layout(packed, binding = 0) readonly buffer matrix_buffer
{
    mat4x4 matrix[];
};

...

gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0.0f, 1.0) * matrix[gl_InstanceID];
//works
```

My GL code basically looks like this:

```
std::vector<glm::mat3> matrix(8192, glm::mat3(1.0f));
glNamedBufferStorageEXT(buffer, sizeof(matrix[0]) * matrix.size(), matrix.data(), 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, buffer);

//example2

std::vector<glm::mat4> matrix(8192, glm::mat4(1.0f));
glNamedBufferStorageEXT(buffer, sizeof(matrix[0]) * matrix.size(), matrix.data(), 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, buffer);
```

I've tried std140 and std430 layouts as well.

Comment: I would suggest `std140` and the appropriate padding for alignment purposes. A 3x3 matrix cannot be packed contiguously, you will need to query `GL_UNIFORM_ARRAY_STRIDE​` if you use the `packed` layout qualifier. If, on the other hand, you use `std140` you are guaranteed that your array of `mat3x3` will be padded such that it has the same base alignment as an array of `vec4`. `mat4` is free of any sort of alignment unfriendliness, as you have already noticed. `vec3` and `mat3x3` are very nasty things to put into a buffer... GPUs prefer data to have 1,2 or 4 components :)

Comment: If it was an issue with padding, then shouldn't the first matrix in the array be valid? Even using just matrix[0] results in nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see. The padding is in each row of the matrix.

Comment: Did that fix your problem? I am always hesitant to write full answers for buffer alignment issues related to matrices because that part of the OpenGL specification (***7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout***) is ridiculously difficult to quote. It includes 10 bullet points and the relevant points in this case each reference 3-4 other bullet points.